# How to populate a collection property from SqlDataReader?

Tags: sql, ado.net, mapping, left-join, sqldatareader

I have this simple SQL query:

```
SELECT  CustomerName, OrderId 
FROM    Customer c
        LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

I need to populate my Customer entity from the query result:

```
public class Customer
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> OrderIds { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm reading data with SqlDataReader:

```
using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{      
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
     Customer c = new Customer();
     c.Name = rdr["CustomerName"].ToString();      
     yield return c;
    }
}
```

**Question**: What is the simplest and cleanest way to fill in the **OrderIds** property without using an ORM? The left join causes the query to return multiple rows per customer (because each customer has multiple orders) so now reading it row by row like the above code won't work? Is there any way to fill that entity and still use yield return for deferred execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st version:

```
var customersRDR = from rCustomers in rdr.Cast<DbDataRecord>()
                   group rCustomers by rCustomers["CustomerName"] into custGroups
                   select new Customer
                   {
                      Name = (string)custGroups.Key,
                      OrderIds = from c in custGroups select (Int32)c["OrderId"]
                   };
```

2nd version:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rdr);

var customers = from c in dt.AsEnumerable()
                group c by c["CustomerName"] into custGroups
                select new Customer{
                   Name = custGroups.Key.ToString(),
                   OrderIds = from c in custGroups select Convert.ToInt32(c["OrderId"])
               };
```

3rd version:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(rdr);

var customerGroups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(c => c["CustomerName"]);

foreach (var customer in customerGroups){
     Customer cust = new Customer();
     cust.Name = customerGroup.Key.ToString();
     cust.OrderIds = from c in customerGroup select Convert.ToInt32(c["OrderId"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> orderIds = (from IDataRecord r in rdr
                      where (string) r["CustomerName"] == c.Name
                      select (int)r["OrderIds"]).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

This a bit tricky to do without an ORM. However another option is to use multiple readers. It would require you to have two queries - one for customer and one for orders. As an example:

```
    private void GetCustomerWithOrders()
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
        {
            using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT CustomerName, CustomerId FROM Customer";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var customerId = reader.GetInt32(1); // CustomerId
                        List<int> orders = GetOrders(customerId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private List<int> GetOrders(int customerId)
    {
        var orders = new List<int>();
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connectionstring"))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT OrderId FROM Orders WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId", conn))
            {
                var param = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@CustomerId",
                    Value = customerId
                };

                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var orderId = reader.GetInt32(0); // OrderId
                        orders.Add(orderId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return orders;
    }
```

Comment: This will get the first customer's orders correctly, but then it won't read the rows of the next customer, because when you iterate on all rows of the reader ("from IDataRecord r in rdr") you actually reach the end of the datareader (rdr.Read() == false - no more rows left to read).

Comment: @BornToCode I've updated my answer. Hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

var dataTable = new DataTable();

dataTable.Load(dataReader);
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, it's always good to explain how your code helps the OP.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - it just wraps the raw query results in a datatable object, but I'd like to map the results to a collection of my `Customer` objects.